# Converting bash script to python

Tags: linux, shell, python

I am trying to convert a bash script to a python. This is the bash code:

```
number=1
/sbin/lsof -i -P -s tcp:LISTEN | while read -r line; do

 if [ "$number" -eq 1 ] ; then
         number=$((number+1))
         continue
 fi

 a_pid=`/bin/echo "$line" | /bin/awk '{print $2}'`

 ps_line=`/bin/ps h -fp "$lsof_pid"`
 ps_cmd="${ps_line#*/}"
 a_u=`/bin/echo "$line" | /bin/awk '{print $3}'`
 a_t=`/bin/echo "$line" | /bin/awk '{print $5}'`
 a_p=`/bin/echo "$line" | /bin/awk '{print $9}' | /bin/cut -d":" -f 2`

 service_line=$(/bin/grep " ${lsof_port}/tcp" /etc/services)
 port_name=`/bin/echo "$service_line" | /bin/awk '{print $1}'`

 done
```

And this is what I have so far for Python:

```
import subprocess
number=1
subprocess.call(['/sbin/lsof', '-i', '-P', '-s', 'tcp:LISTEN'],shell=True)

while line.readline():
        if(number==1):
                count=(number+1)
```

It works so far. However, I'm not sure how I would convert the a_p files to python without calling the function (I essentially need to filter the data to a readable format with specific columns). I am not even sure if I am doing the while function correctly, but it doesn't give me any errors, thus far so can't really tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works so far?  :-)  I don't think so.  When I try to execute in python3, it just hangs at the `subprocess` statement.  Where is `line` defined? You never increment `number` or `count`. You'll have to find out how to access the output of the `subprocess` in your `while` loop.

I think that you're on a good track.

I would do something like this:

- Read up on `subprocess`.
- Print `line` in that loop to see what your working with.
- Print `count` after the loop.
- You'll need another `subprocess` to run `ps`.
- Replace all of the functionality provided by `echo`, `awk`, `cut`,
  and `grep` with direct Python code.
- Read the man pages for `awk`, `cut`, and `grep` to understand what those commands are doing in the shell script.
- To find out how to do those things in Python, begin by looking at the
  Python String Methods documentation.  Almost everything you need to
  do will be in String Methods and Subprocess.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ah didn't notice but it gives an error on the while command https://i.imgur.com/JgcHymt.png , seems like so far it only outputs the subprocess. I'll read up on the documentations since I really only know the very basics of Python currently and figure out how to access the output of the subprocess in the while loop.